# Sweater training my pig

Tags: behavior, training, pig

I have [a ~5mo (mostly) American mini-pig/potbelly mix.](https://media.giphy.com/media/kH66z7rfbxAcHn1reM/giphy.gif)

It's starting to get a little colder where I am, and already the little guy is getting hesitant to go outside (and shivering/running back in when he does).

We got him a dog sweater [similar to this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VC64LX8) that fits him well. However, whenever we put it on him, he starts walking funny and jumps around until he manages to slip his legs out of the holes (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DInnx.jpg)). From there he walks around a bit until he slides out of the sweater entirely.

I don't blame him for not liking the feel, but it's only getting colder outside and we do still need to take him out (to go to the bathroom at least, but hopefully for walks too).

Ordinarily, I'd just leave it on until he got used to the feel like a collar or harness, but since he slips out of the sweater almost immediately after we put it on and let him down, that doesn't seem to be an option. **How can we train him to keep it on and get used to it?**

I'm imagining the solutions will probably be pretty similar to what you'd do with a dog or cat in the same situation, so I'd be open to hearing those kinds of answers as well!